# Why can i not access attributes from another class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im making a userProfile class in swift which includes the following code:

```
class userProfile {

    var firstname: String!
    var username: String!
    var lastname: String!
    var uid: String!

     init(uid: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

         self.uid = uid

         if let username = dictionary["username"]as? String {
             self.username = username
         }

         if let firstname = dictionary["firstname"]as? String {
             self.firstname = firstname
         }

         if let lastname = dictionary["lastname"]as? String {
             self.lastname = lastname
         }
     }
}
```

and i am trying to access the the attributes in another class with the following code:

```
 var user: userProfile? {
      didSet {
          let fullName = userProfile?.firstname
          firstname.text = fullName
     }
 }
```

But when i do this i get the following error and i don't know why:

**Type 'userProfile?' has no member 'firstname'**

how di i fix this?

Comment: `userProfile?.firstname` ??? `userProfile` is oddly class in your case not instance how do u expect to access instance property in it? `firstname` is String, how do you expect .text property to string? Either the code is not even compiling or given code is not repressing the issue properly

Comment: i dont understand what you are saying. im watching a tutorial and this is how it has been done and it works for them

Comment: You should name your class starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: How do you expect `let fullName = userProfile?.firstname` to run? you have declared a class in your code  `class userProfile`  so `userProfile?.firstname` you are trying to access a instance property named `firstname` from class not instance of class, only way that would work if `firstname` is static variable even in that case ? doesn't make any sense. If you don't know difference between static variable, instance variable, class and instance please start studying programming in any language :)

Comment: @gino-sesia: Seems like you are new to programming :) Do study the fundamentals well to have better grasp of concepts before you go hands-on coding :) Understanding OOPs / POP programming with either Objective-C, Swift or even Java any language for that matter will help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix (you tried to access class, but should be instance) :

```
 var user: userProfile? {
      didSet {
          let fullName = user?.firstname // << here !!

          firstname.text = fullName    // I can't say if this valid
     }
 }
```

To avoid such ambiguity you should follow a rule to name classes in UpperCase, ie. in you case `UserProfile`.